# Find the distribution of distance between two points in circle

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

In circle with radius $1$ two points are independently chosen. Find the distribution of distance between these points.

---

I'm just starting to explore distributions and don't even understand where to start. I'd appreciate a detailed solution

Comment: $\frac{128}{45\pi}$ is the answer you'll get by performing a Google search. What do you make of the process? [Here's a link to an answer elsewhere.](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-average-distance-between-two-random-points-in-a-circle)

Comment: @AndrewChin I may not understand obvious things but I thought distribution is a function whereas $\frac{128}{45\pi}$ is a number

Comment: I have misread. What have you learned about distributions?